# How to parse mail in Ruby-Mail 2.3 like in TMail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

Given that TMail seems to have problems with Ruby 1.9.2 I have tried to use [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) instead. In my old code I had

```
 gmail = Net::IMAP.new(GMAIL_HOST, GMAIL_PORT, GMAIL_SSL)
      gmail.login(GMAIL_USER, GMAIL_PASS)
      gmail.select('Inbox')
      gmail.uid_search(["NOT","SEEN"]).each do |message_id|
      TMail::Mail.parse(gmail.uid_fetch(message_id, 'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822'])
      ....
```

How do I go about implementing the same in Mail?
I've tried

`Mail.read(gmail.uid_fetch(message_id, 'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822'])` and
`Mail::Mail.parse(gmail.uid_fetch(message_id, 'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822'])`

thinking they would be sort of a drop-in replacement but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, ran into this problem today.

Here's the solution I used: [Saving attachments with Rails 3](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/saving-attachments-with-ruby-1-9-2-rails-3-and-the-mail-gem/)

In your case, it'd be:

```
 Mail.new(gmail.uid_fetch(message_id, 'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822'])
```